# Set a custom checkbox field to TRUE based on another checkbox field value and a text field value

Tags: formula, checkbox

I need to set a custom checkbox field to be TRUE based on the values of two other custom fields. The new checkbox field is named 'Is_International_Student__c'. The existing fields are  a checkbox named 'Is_Student__c' and Text field named 'Dental_School__c'.

I need to set 'Is_International_Student__c' = True IF 'Is_Student__c' = True AND 'Dental_School__c' contains ('Mexico%').

Can anyone assist with this?

Comment: Welcome to SFSE. Please take a moment to read [ask] and take the [tour].  We cannot implement your requirements or provide complete designs, but we're happy to help you with issues you encounter in your own implementation process. For more about our format, please take the [tour] and read [ask]. Please [edit] your question to show us what you've tried and where you are stuck.  Have you considered using a Formula field?  If doesn't fit your requirements, then you'll need to build a Flow.  See Salesforce [Trailhead](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/) for tutorials on these and other topics.

Comment: Speficially, the [unit on formula fields](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/content/learn/modules/point_click_business_logic/formula_fields), part of the "formulas and validations" module, itself part of the Admin Intermediate and Platform Developer Beginner trails.

Answer (score 1):

You basically already wrote the formula down in words.

Create the `Is_International_Student__c` field as a boolean formula field.

Then add the formula:

```
AND(Is_Student__c==TRUE,
    CONTAINS(Dental_School__c,'Mexico')
)
```

If `Dental_School__c` needs to start with "Mexico", then you can update the formula to:

```
AND(Is_Student__c==TRUE,
    LEFT(Dental_School__c,6)=='Mexico'
)
```

Good luck!

Comment: N.B., best practice is to avoid the `== true (or false)` to make the formulas simpler. I.e. `AND(Is_Student__c,CONTAINS(Dental_SChool__c,'Mexico'))`

Comment: This is perfect. Thanks!!

Comment: @AndrewJaffee glad to hear it 

Comment: @AndrewJaffee mind marking my response as the answer?